# Object with a strong reference to it is being destroyed before the reference goes out of scope?

Tags: perl, oop, destructor, weak-references

I have the following Perl code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

# Parent object
package Parent;
{
    use Moose;

    has 'children' => (is => 'rw', isa => 'ArrayRef[Child]', default => sub { [] });
}

# Child object
package Child;
{
    use Moose;

    has 'parent' => (is => 'ro', isa => 'Parent', required => 1);

    # Child DEMOLISHER!!!! >:)
    sub DEMOLISH {
        my ($self) = @_;

        # Loop through the known children of the parent
        for my $index (0 .. $#{$self->parent->children()}) {

            # Remove the destroyed child
            if ($self->parent->children->[$index] == $self) {
                splice @{$self->parent->children()}, $index, 1;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

package Test;
{
    use Scalar::Util qw(weaken);
    use Data::Dumper;

    # Create a parent object
    my $parent = Parent->new();
    {
    
        # Create children (with STRONG refs to the parent)
        my $child  = Child->new('parent' => $parent);
        my $child2 = Child->new('parent' => $parent);
        my $child3 = Child->new('parent' => $parent);

        # Add children to the parents list of children
        push @{$parent->children()}, ($child, $child2, $child3);

        # Weaken the last childref
        weaken($parent->children->[-1]);

        # Print the children
        print Dumper($parent->children());
    }

    # The weakened child is out of scope and should be removed
    print Dumper($parent->children());
}
```

This code creates a parent object, then creates 3 child objects (each with a strong reference to the parent).  Then one child is weakened.  When the children go out of scope it is expected that the weakened child will be DESTROYED and removed from the parent's `children` array (wow that sounds brutal) while the other two children remain.

However upon running this code I get the following output:

[image]

With these error messages:

> **Use of uninitialized value in numeric eq (==) at line 28 during global destruction.**
>
> **(in cleanup) Can't call method "children" on an undefined value at line 25 during global destruction.**

Now to clarify this error . . .

line 25 is this line: `for my $index (0 .. $#{$self->parent->children()}) {`

It is failing to call `$self->parent()`! (This can be tested by trying to print the value of `$self->parent()`)

---

The error appears to indicate that the child is being destroyed AFTER the parent has already been destroyed, so the parent is now undefined.  **BUT** the child object being destroyed contains a **STRONG** reference to the parent and thus should not allow the parent object to be destroyed until AFTER the child is destroyed.

How can this be?

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you are trying to say? The code works I'm just wondering why it claims that the parent no longer exists.  It shouldn't allow the parent object to be destroyed until all of the children are destroyed.  ACTUALLY the other 2 children should never be destroyed either since the parent contains strong references to both of them.

Comment: You have a memory reference cycle causing a memory leak. But the leaked objects are still deallocated on program exit. But since they weren't properly freed, they may not be freed in the order you expect.

Comment: @ikegami, are you saying that since the parent references the children and the 2 non weak children reference the parent that Perl doesn't know which one to destroy first at the end of the script so it just chooses one?

Comment: I didn't study the code to determine what the leak is, but your objects are surviving past the end of the block in which your lexicals are declared because they are getting freed *during global destruction*, which happens after the file has finished executing.

Comment: @ikegami, that makes sense.  This code appears to work without errors (and all 3 children are destroyed) if i weaken all 3 children like so: `map { weaken($_) } @{$parent->children()}`

Comment: This may be the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: `weaken($_) for @{$parent->children()};`  would be more idiomatic. `map`'s intended use is to translate one list into another.

Comment: Ah you're right, I always forget I can just use a postfix for loop.